# Network compression for Python / Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, networking, compression

I have a Python script that queries a remote MongoDB database. The query results are pretty large (~650MB). But the documents that mongo sends are extremely compressible because they have lots of plain text. Is there some way that I can insert a compression "proxy" of some sort in between my Python script and the Mongo server - either by modifying the code or using some sort of network utility?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing code: how are you requesting the data from Mongo?

Comment: I'm using PyMongo to do the queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want simple solution you can connect to the remote host over compressed ssh tunnel. Assuming you run mongod on default port and 27017 is free on localhost:

```
ssh -C -L 27017:127.0.0.1:27017 remote_user@mongohost
```

It seems to work pretty well at least on dummy data. You can even use [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/) to create ssh tunnel ([How to create a ssh tunnel using python and paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169739/how-to-create-a-ssh-tunnel-using-python-and-paramiko)) and keep everything wrapped inside Python code.

Comment: This seems like it might be a good solution. I know it's counter to ssh's purpose, but is there a way to turn off encryption so as to not slow down the transfer?

Comment: Out of the box no. In case of OpenSSH you can recompile it to enable unencrypted connections but I think it won't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

[MongoDB 3.4](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3018) added support for network compression using Snappy. Its not enabled by default though (use `networkMessageCompressors=snappy` to enable it).

[MongoDB 3.6 added support for zlib](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27310) compression, and enabled network compression by default.

To use it in [drivers](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DRIVERS-381) (such as [pymongo](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1278)) add "compressors=zlib" to your configure string:

```
mongodb://localhost/?compressors=zlib
```