# python paramiko ssh client then ssh to another server again

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Please help me! I am quite new in paramiko.

I faced a problem when I used paramiko connect to Host_A but I need ssh Host_B with the same password again in Host_A.

How can I do?  Thanks in advance.

```
hostname = 'Host_A'
port = 22
username = 'username' 
password = 'password'
client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
client.connect(username=username, password=password)
```

[python paramiko ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745138/python-paramiko-ssh)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to say that in Host_B. I need to execute a commend (like 'ls' )  then output the results.

Comment: you want to ssh to hostA and then from hostA to hostB?

Comment: Another similar questions: [How to create a ssh tunnel using python and paramiko?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8169739/850848) and [Port forwarding with paramiko](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11294919/850848).