# Paramiko for remote ssh

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I have a common VM and remote VM. we have network devices, only remote VM has access to network devices.

Python script will do configurations in network devices.

I must  trigger a python script from common VM.

To implement this Currently I have two options in my mind.

1. Configure password less between common vm to remote vm. Trigger a script from common vm which copies script to remote vm then start execution.
2. directly ssh using paramiko to remote  and again ssh using paramiko to network devices (This option is not tried, I am going to try now)

Which is the better method or any other suggestions will welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your second solution. My prefered would be to [use a ssh tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169739/how-to-create-a-ssh-tunnel-using-python-and-paramiko)

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Comment: @Michael Doubez, ssh tunnel is to connect remote server, that is possible using  stardard paramiko module, again from from remote server I have to establish another remote connection ..